# Laravel Dingo API - How to respond with multiple collections / transformers?

Tags: php, json, laravel, api-design, dingo-api

To initialize my app I have the following route:

`/initialize`

This returns Taxonomies, Enumerables and a couple of other taxonomy like collections. This saves multiple HTTP requests.

Although with Dingo / Fractal, I cannot see how I can respond with multiple collections?

e.g.

```
return [
    'taxonomies' => $this->response->collection($taxonomies, new TaxonomyTransformer);
    'enumerables' => $this->response->collection($enumerables, new EnumerableTransformer);
    'otherStuff' => $this->response->collection($otherStuff, new OtherStuffTransformer);
];
```

Comment: ```return response()->json([
    'data' =>  [
        'taxonomies' => $this->fractal->collection($taxonomies, new TaxonomyTransformer);
        'enumerables' => $this->fractal->collection($enumerables, new EnumerableTransformer);
        'otherStuff' => $this->fractal->collection($otherStuff, new OtherStuffTransformer);
    ] 
], 200);```

need to know how to remove {headers,exceptions,origin} 

from the above response?

Answer (score 1):

```
return response()->json([
    'data' =>  [
        'taxonomies' => $this->fractal->collection($taxonomies, new TaxonomyTransformer);
        'enumerables' => $this->fractal->collection($enumerables, new EnumerableTransformer);
        'otherStuff' => $this->fractal->collection($otherStuff, new OtherStuffTransformer);
    ] 
], 200);
```

This should return the JSON in the format you are looking for.

Comment: That wil not work, as `$this->response->collection( ...` will include normal response information such as `{ headers, exceptions }`

Comment: What kind of headers and exceptions? For each resource or those are the  common headers and exceptions?

Comment: Oh I see, shouldn't you replace the `$this->response->collection()` with the fractal objects for each class like:

`$this->fractal->collection($taxonomies, new TaxonomyTransformer)`  

So you can get the values there and have one response object instead of one for each class?

Comment: I don't think $this->fractal is valid. To achieve this, it looks like one must be able to grab an instance of the fractal manager class and use its createData and toArray methods to generate the necessary transformed data. I'm not sure though how you would do that with Dingo since the $transformer property of the Response class is protected, else it would have been possible with ```$manager = $this->response->transformer->getFractal()``` on your controller.

Comment: You can use the Fractal manager without Dingo. You don't need Dingo for everything.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue ,and  I found the solution from [How to use Transformer in one to many relationship. #1054](https://github.com/dingo/api/issues/1054).
Here is the collection I want to return with the transfomer of dingo in my controller.

```
$user = User::where('email','=',$input['email'])->with('departments')->with('roles')->get();
```

DepartmentTransformer

```
class DepartmentTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    public function transform($department)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $department['id'],
            'name' => $department['name'],
            'level' => $department['level'],
            'parent_id' => $department['parent_id']
        ];
    }
}
```

RolesTransformer

```
class RolesTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    public function transform($role)
    {
        return [
            'name' => $role['name'],
            'slug' => $role['slug'],
            'description' => $role['description'],
            'level' => $role['level']
        ];
    }

}
```

UserTransformer

```
class UserTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    protected $defaultIncludes = ['departments','roles'];


    public function transform($user)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $user['id'],
            'name' => $user['name'],
            'email' => $user['email'],
            'phone' => $user['phone'],
        ];
    }


    public function includeDepartments(User $user)
    {
        $dept  = $user->departments;

        return $this->collection($dept, new DepartmentTransformer());
    }


    public function includeRoles(User $user)
    {
        $rl = $user->roles;

        return $this->collection($rl, new RolesTransformer());
    }
}
```

In my controller

```
$user = User::where('email','=',$input['email'])->with('departments')->with('roles')->get();

return $this->response->collection($user, new UserTransformer());
```

And I got the result

```
            "data": {
            {
                "id": 43,
              "name": "test7",
              "email": "test7@foxmail.com",
              "phone": "186********",
              "departments": {
                "data": {
                  {
                      "id": 1,
                    "name": "业务一部",
                    "level": 1,
                    "parent_id": 0
                  }
                }
              },
              "roles": {
                "data": {
                  {
                      "name": "agent",
                    "slug": "agent",
                    "description": "业务员",
                    "level": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

Please take note of the usage of $defaultIncludes and includeXXX() methonds in the UserTransformer.You can get more detail info from [Fractal Doc](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/).

Comment: While a link to a potential solution is always welcome, an answer on Stack Overflow should always contain the main parts/points of the solution in the answer body itself. Merely a link to a solution with no further commentary is not considered an acceptable answer. See [ask] on how to formulate a proper answer.